# How Do I Write JUnit tests to test that a function doesn't accept an incorrect type?

Tags: java, junit

I'm writing tests for some code I was given. There is a constructor that takes and int as the first parameter. I want to test that it gives an error if something such as a boolean is passed in so I wrote this code.

```
try
{
    nanReview = new WorkshopReview(true, "test");
}
catch (Error err)
{
    assertEquals(err.getMessage(), "incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int");
}
```

When I run the test it just throws the error into the console again, shouldn't the test pass at this point because it throws the expected error message?

How do I go about testing stuff like this / should I even be testing this in the first place?

Comment: It shouldn't be "throwing the error into the console again" - you're catching it.  Are you sure your code actually throws an `Error` (and not an `Exception`)?

Comment: Does your constructor actually throw an `Error`? It shouldn't. Are you aware of the differences between `Error`, `Exception` and `Throwable`?

Comment: Please show us your constructor.  It it takes `int`, then passing `boolean` should not compile, and hence need not be unit tested.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the differences. I know Error and Exception are subclasses of Throwable. The constructor does not throw anything. And thanks Alexander for saying I don't need to test that. So I should only be unit testing things that compile but that I don't want to happen e.g. passing negative integers into the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

This will not do what you want. If the constructor succeeds, the test passes.

While JUnit has an `expected` parameter to its `@Test` annotation, I personally prefer using assertj:

```
try {
    iShouldThrow();
    shouldHaveThrown(SomeException.class);
} catch (SomeException e) {
    assertThat(e).hasMessage(whatever);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `ExpectedException` framework -> http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html.  I used to do what you've shown, but the `ExpectedException` framework makes tests more clear.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak disagree; what is more, with this way of doing it, you cannot inspect, for instance, the causes, suppressed exceptions etc.